# simple 301 redirect with ISAPI_Rewrite

Tags: isapi-rewrite

i need to reditrect 
this url 
http://www.mydomain.com/folder/Templates/ShowPage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=1&TMID=10000&FID=579

to 
http://www.mydomain.com/folder/Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=1&TMID=302&FID=569

i'm using "Helicon Tech : ISAPI_Rewrite 3.0" on server 2003 iis 6

i tried

```
RewriteRule ^folder/templates/showpage\.asp?dbid=1&lngid=1&tmid=10000&fid=579$ /folder/templates/showpage.asp?dbid=1&lngid=1&tmid=302&fid=569 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using:
(You may ommit 'RewriteBase /' directive, then use '/' in front of 'folder/...')

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DBID=1&LNGID=1&TMID=10000&FID=579$ [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^folder/Templates/ShowPage.asp$ /folder/Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=1&TMID=302&FID=569? [NC,L]
```

Comment: This looks ok, but I don't think `[NC,L]` belongs on the RewriteCond line, and he wanted a redirect, so the RewriteRule should have `[NC,R=301]`.